# How to use node and quill?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, quill

I want to try [quill](http://quilljs.com) in my express.js app. So, I can install it using

```
npm install quill
```

but **how do I actually use it with node**?

I don't really understand why this is a node package since it basically only consists of a .css and a .js file and can be included directly inside the template which also makes most sense to me, because that's where the rich text editor takes effect.

Comment: Are you using a bundler?

Comment: @Phillip what do you mean?

Comment: For example if you use webpack you can just `require('quill')` and it and its dependencies will be bundled together with the rest of your application.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a thread where one of the creators of quill (jhchen) was asked just that. I hope that helps someone.

Question:

> Then what is the npm install command for?
>   Pretty much every application people build nowadays uses Browserify or Webpack to build things before the browser renders it, and if you can't even require() it, then how can you use it?

Answer:

> You can absolutely require Quill for the purposes of building with Webpack or Browserify. You just can't run Quill in the Node.js REPL.

source: https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/1194